# Chrome console not finding some child elements inside form element with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, dom-manipulation

I'm trying to remove an element from the DOM with javascript.
I'm testing with the chrome dev tools in the console.
In the elements tab I see a form with his children, but when I select the form with javascript and print to the console a div and anchor tag are removed.

In the elements inspector I have this block of HTML.
[image]

Its a form elements with 3 input tags, 1 div and 1 anchor.
I the console I'm typing:

```
const input = document.querySelector("input[value='41503038898315']")
const form = input.closest('form')
```

Until this point I'm succesfully selecting both elements. The problem is when I try to querySelector the div I want to remove, is ignoring it.

And when I print the form, I only get the 3 inputs. The div and a are gone.
[image]

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that this is the same form? Maybe there are two almost identical ones

Comment: Feel free to delete the question

Comment: Do not use images, put the source. :-)